# Duda sobre la utilización del método array.every

Tags: javascript

estoy practicando resolviendo ejercicios de la página codeSignal y me he encontrado con uno llamado "avoidObstacles" el cual, aunque lo he resuelto (no con menos de 20 líneas de código) he mirado la solución de otros que lo han realizado con anterioridad y la que mejor puntuación tiene es una función que no entiendo como trabaja y que ha conseguido resolver el ejercicio con un par de líneas.

Esta la resolución en cuestión:

```
function avoidObstacles(arr = []) {
for (var n = 1; ; n++) {
    if (arr.every((x) => x % n)) return n;
    }
}
```

Y esta es la captura del ejercicio:

[image: captura ejercicio]

Saludos

Comment: efectivamente, la duda queda resuelta. Cualquier resultado el al función callback que sea "0" devolvería false en la comprobación del every.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si piensas en el problema en términos de una división, lo que buscas es un número que no sea un divisor exacto de *ninguno* de los espacios donde hay obstáculos (es decir, que su *módulo* no sea 0). Si un número divide exactamente alguno de los obstáculos, caerías eventualmente.
Lo que hace esa respuesta es buscar el menor número posible en el que el módulo de *todos* los elementos sea un valor diferente a 0.

La función [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) verifica que una condición se cumpla en *todos* los elementos del array. En este caso la condición es que el módulo no sea 0.
Como la iteración se hace en orden, el primer número que haga cumplir esa condición es la respuesta.

---

Ejemplo:

```
const isBelowThreshold = (currentValue) => currentValue < 40;

const array1 = [1, 30, 39, 29, 10, 13];

console.log(array1.every(isBelowThreshold));
// salida esperada: true
```

En este ejemplo si todos los elementos del `array1` son menores a **40** se espera `true` como resultado.

Más ejemplos e información [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).